# How to get next value from List<string>

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I have problem with List string. I put 3 values into myCollection

```
List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

myCollection.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(data));
myCollection.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(data2));
myCollection.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(data3));
```

and now i have 3 values : A,B,C

but now i want to block buttons with contains this values :

```
for (var i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)

{

    if (myCollection.Contains(A))
    {

        this.A.Enabled = false;

    }

    else if (myCollection.Contains(B))
    {

        this.B.Enabled = false;
    }

    else if (myCollection.Contains(C))
    {

        this.C.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

After this loop just first button=false. Now loop done 3 times this same try block button A and my question is: 
How block other buttons?

Now i get in first loop run:

```
  this.A.Enabled = false;

2nd this.A.Enabled = false;


3rd this.A.Enabled = false;
```

but i want :

```
1st :   this.A.Enabled = false;

2nd :   this.B.Enabled = false;

3rd :   this.C.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Why are you putting this in a loop? And why are you even using a list?

Comment: Is `A` a button or a string?

Comment: Do you mean to say `if (myCollection.Contains("A"))` instead of `if (myCollection.Contains(A))`? If so, please edit the question.

Comment: @GrantWinney yeah, you're right, just got off a JS binge the last week.. his update to his question, overwrote it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this. Just use simple `if` statements without `else`.

```
if (myCollection.Contains("A"))
    this.A.Enabled = false;

if (myCollection.Contains("B"))
    this.B.Enabled = false;

if (myCollection.Contains("C"))
    this.C.Enabled = false;
```

Mainly the `else` was causing problems for you. If the condition for A was true, then the code for B and C did not run. This is how `else` works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, but your problem here is that you use if..else. If any of the conditions is true, the rest won't be resolved.

To solve your problem just remove the else keywords from your conditions.

Also, the loop is unnecesary when you use Contains.

If you'd insist on the loop, you would have to change the condition a bit, and then the else would be properly used:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)            
      {
        if (myCollection[i] == A)
        {
            this.A.Enabled = false;                   
        }

        else if (myCollection[i] == B)
        {
            this.B.Enabled = false;
        }

        else if (myCollection[i] == C)
        {
            this.C.Enabled = false;
        }
      }
```